# Spring data CRUD methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

We use spring data, the whole point of which is to be able to just use the provided interfaces (such as e.g. CrudRepository) and not have to actually implement stuff.

We have realized that we need to take steps to make sure that our app:

- escapes illegal HTML characters such as & < > " ' from input
- has protection against sql injections

and to me the most logical place do to that would seem to be somewhere high up in the generic db methods that all our repos share. But since they are not implemented anywhere in our code I dont know if this already implemented in spring data or not.

Comment: spring-data-jpa takes care of SQL injection for you

Regarding input sanitization, the usual architecture is DAOs / Services / Controllers, and I think the input should be "handled" into services.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to be mixing two very different concerns here, so let's discuss them separately:

1. The protection against SQL injection is to be found in the corresponding SQL-ish spring-data implementation: JDBC or JPA; so you shouldn't need to worry about it. The generic API doesn't expose anything related to this simply because it's generic and "SQL injection" sounds really weird when you're using HBase, for instance.
2. Escaping HTML stuff is a whole different thing since it's a concern of your presentation layer, not your data layer. So you can either escape the input at validation time, before sending it to the repository or sanitize the output afterwards, when you want to display stored data in the UI.

As a note, HTML is just one of the formats your data can be delivered as. If you later on need to also produce JSON or CSV, you will end up mixing escapes for different formats in the database. This is an obvious reason why escaping is not part of the DAO layer and why output sanitization is the safe way to go here.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. OK, so while we dont have to worry about sql injections, there is still the escaping illegal HTML characters. Our db already contains saved input that contains illegal HTML characters. We will try to use a db script to get rid of them. As for preventing further input of illegal characters, Im not sure where to do it. I dont really care about validation and informing users that they have illegal characters in their input I just want a centralized method that escapes them. (= identifies and repaces them with character codes) Do you have any recommendations where to do it?

Comment: "Output sanitization" means you don't need to prevent illegal HTML stuff from getting into your DB, but rather you need to prevent it from getting to the browser. So you may choose to store data as it comes but then preprocess it before rendering.

Comment: One other reason against a db script: what if you find out some other illegal character later (which you haven't considered when you wrote the DB script). You'll end up with several scripts for several "versions" of your data. If you sanitize it after extracting from DB, that code can be enhanced with no worries about the stored data.

Comment: As for where to place this code, I would suggest the UI layer (the controller of you MVC), unless this is not just a mere presentation issue but a hard business requirement. In this latter case, the service layer would be the best fit for such code.

Answer (score 0):

To address your concerns about `escapes illegal HTML characters such as & < > " ' from input`

You should consider using:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(str)
```

in your service layer

for more information about this class, see [StringEscapeUtils JavaDocs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)